# How to recognize an IP filter with nmap from two different locations?

Tags: vpn, internet, ip, nmap

I am using a VPN (PPTP) connection in Windows to connect to a company. I can do this inside my own company, I cannot connect from home.

I did an nmap from my own company onto this IP address, PPTP 1723 shows as open.

I did an nmap from home onto this IP address, PPTP 1723 shows as filtered.

Question: Why?

Is there an IP filter?